# ASUS G51J - GPU overheats when plugged in to power, does not on battery power

Tags: power-management, cooling, gpu

The ASUS G51J comes with an nvidia GeForce GTX 260M.

Running Windows 7.

Running FurMark Stability Test, Full Screen, 640x480, MSAA Samples: NONE

FPS starts at about 50, GPU Temp at about 100' C.

FPS decreases as temperature rises. By about the 30-60 second mark, depending on the starting GPU temperature, the GPU temp is at 110' and FPS drops into single digits.

I see this same kind of single digit FPS drop while playing regular 3D games as well, for example, World of Warcraft, even with all details set to low at small resolutions.

If I unplug the power from the laptop and then run FurMark, it runs
just fine and the temperature does not increase beyond ~85' C. As soon
as I plug the power in, the temperature starts to shoot up, continuing
until it gets to about 110' C.

I've messed with all the power settings, but nothing there makes a difference.

This laptop did at one time play games with no trouble. It is almost a year old and is under warranty. Time to send it in? Or is there anything else I can try? I'm thinking my next move is to boot into an Ubuntu Live CD and try to duplicate the problem.

Comment: One would assume when it is on battery the bios clocks back the processor and possibly the gpu. Try cleaning the vents and fan. Some reviews say it runs hot anyway...https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=ASUS+G51J+runs+hot&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right.  A can of compressed air solved my problem. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll give you some rep.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Moab mentioned in the comment, the temperature drop when on battery power was due to the CPU/GPU underclocking themselves. The solution for the overheating was using a can of compressed gas to blow out the hidden accumulation of dust inside the fan housing.